# How can I add and remove files from an ISO image?

Tags: delphi, archive, iso9660

Are there any (preferably free) components or libraries that handle ISO files?

In particular I would like to be able to add files and save to ISO, as well as extract the files from an ISO.

I do not require advanced features or bells and whistles, just something to do what I mentioned above.

I tried to find some but came up with nothing really.

Perhaps this can be done without the need of such a library? If so what approach would you recommend?

Comment: Note to closers: This is, in fact, a programming question.

Comment: Thanks Will, yes this is a programming question as I need to know how to handle ISO files from Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the [TIsoLib component](http://sourceforge.net/projects/isolib) and the [FreeBurner library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeburner/) which is a fork of the first, and seems more complete?

Otherwise, I know about the [Binary Magic component](http://www.binarymagics.com/), which is not free, but handles ISO file creation... and burning to CD.

*Addition:*

You may take a look at the `mkisofs` command line tool. It's [part of the *cdrtools* project](http://freshmeat.net/projects/cdrecord/), and is the root component of .iso creation in the Linux world. You can call this tool from command line, add and delete files from an .iso file. I've seen several commercial programs which use it to create boot CDs on the fly, from Windows. Be aware of the GPL license: you'll have to [make a clear distinction between your software and the GPL software](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem).

Comment: The FreeBurner component was mentioned before this thread was moved. Unfortunately I am using Delphi XE and neither does the ISO Lib or FreeBurner Lib work. I did successfully get FreeBurner installed in Delphi XE after making some Unicode conversions, but there were too many runtime errors. As for the Binary Magic Components I hear the customer support is really bad so I am a bit apprehensive of buying one of their packages. Thanks for the reccomendations though +1

Comment: @Craig I didn't see the original thread, sorry... Binary Magic has such a bad reputation (pseudo-company in Germany with random support from Pakistan as far as I was told from one of their clients), but I've seen Delphi software using it without any issue. I've added mkisofs to my answer list... just in case you were not thinking of this well known and supported open source solution. You can [embed an external program to your main exe, if you want](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=314#p314).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will be of help to someone... (hopefully it will save them some time) but I know that using WinRAR at the moment does NOT seem to give the desired result in at least one encounter. I used it to extract an installation media, which resulted in a file not being found, during using the extracted files. I would like to see others trying out the extraction and let the problem re-occur, so that the cause of this can be found, fixed, at thus WinRAR become a better tool in doing what you asked for.
Note: If someone feel this is not appropriate, I am really sorry, I am just trying to help, please close my answer in this case.

see [ISO-Extraction](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/d5f32eee-2c7a-4883-af3e-cbdcd6d942d5/?prof=required)